# Charts.js candlestick (Financial Charts) Timeformat Question

Tags: chart.js, finance, candlestick-chart

I want to fill the chart with data I pull via PHP from an API. For some reason I have issues to format the date correctly so the chart currently shows no bars with my data.

A data set from the random data looks like this:
{"t":1494806400000,"o":"35.19","h":"36.79","l":"33.94","c":"36.15"}

One from me like this:
{"t":1591092000,"o":"33.3900","h":"34.2000","l":"32.4100","c":"34.1900"}

I see that there are three 0 missing in mine, but even when I add them it's not working.
I have also checked the dates at https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php to find a difference but the original dates is outputted as 01/05/49229 @ 12:00am (UTC) which looks very odd to me.

Can anyone tell me in which format the date needs to be? d M Y h:i:s is what I currently do in php, but it neither works without the seconds.

Answer (score 0):

5-months later:
I would recommend looking into the Luxon Library to get the values for t,
[https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js%7EDateTime.html)

Other wise I do believe its Year Month Day hours:minutes:seconds

Comment: Don't post how long it's been since the OP was created in your answer, thank you.